# Fail to continue after for ..() do xyz command in Windows command shell

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, command-line

I have two Windows batch files, the first one contains a **FOR** looping command:

```
echo off
for /f %%1 in (somefile.txt) do something %%1
echo then more commands...
```

Then the second file **something.bat** contains a GCP BigQuery command, such as below.  Notice the replaceable **%%1** parameter supplied to it by the first batch file.

```
call bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "WITH intermediate AS (SELECT service.description AS SERVICE,
service.id as ID, invoice.month as MONTH, (SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64)) + 
SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64)) FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000 
AS COST FROM myproject.billingexport.gcp_billing_export_v1_022EAF_F204503_AR2346 WHERE service.id =
\"%1\" group by 1, 2, 3)  SELECT distinct SERVICE, (SELECT round(cast(COST as float64),2) 
FROM intermediate WHERE MONTH = \"202001\") as Jan, FROM intermediate"
```

The commands work fine when executed one-by-one. But when the **FOR** command in file #1 completes, the rest of the batch file is skipped, and execution stops.  I have tried various combinations of **CALL** (or absent that), or moving the **>>** output redirect from the **FOR** command versus in the something.bat.  Nothing obvious seems amiss--must be something simple.  Ideas??  Thanks.

Comment: You should always use `CALL` when executing another batch file from a batch file if you want control to return to the parent batch file.  I am not a big fan of using numbers for the `FOR` variable.  Best practice is to also use `delims=` as to make sure none of the lines of the input file get tokenized.  `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (file.txt) DO CALL something.bat "%%~G"`. That is my best practice at least.

Comment: I believe that is the answer, Squashman!  A thousand thank you's!  DO CALL did the trick.  I don't know if the CALL on the front of the BQ command makes any difference, have not tested that yet, but it doesn't seem to have an issue.